# Zola static site generator and localization (l10n)

Tags: localization, static-site-generation, tera, zola

## The problem

I'm new to Zola and its templating engine Tera, and I'm struggling with making my own Zola theme easily localizable, even providing some out-of-the-box translations for e.g. English and German. Zolas's fluent integration is not there yet - as of Zola v0.17.2 and AFAIK. This problem is not about a multi-language theme, but only about enabling easy localization.

## My "hacky" solution

Consider this text on a page where a blog post is published as an example:
`Published on July 04, 2023`. I want to localize the static text and the dynamic date, and its format.

In the `config.toml` file, I have `default_language = "en"`, where the language can be set to another language with some existing language-specific resources. I do not want these resources to end up in my `config.toml` file, but they should be in a different file for each language.

Therefore, I use the `data` directory with e.g. these files: `en-translations.toml`, and `de-translations.toml`. The first file looks like this, the other has the same keys, just different values:

```
# Global settings
settings_date_locale = "en_US"
settings_date_format = "%B %d, %Y"

# Language resources
published_on = "Published on"
```

Now, in the base template `base.html`, on which all other template files are based, I load the language-specific resources into a variable called `res`:

```
{% set res         = load_data(path='data/' ~ config.default_language ~ '-translations.toml') %}
{% set date_locale = res.settings_date_locale | default(value="en_US")     %}
{% set date_format = res.settings_date_format | default(value="%B %d, %Y") %}
```

I could reference e.g. `res.settings_date_format` directly, but because I want to have a fallback, I save it in a separate variable.

With this preparation, I can now do the following in every template:

```
<span>
{{ res.published_on }} {{ page.date | date(locale=date_locale, format=date_format) }}
</span>
```

For `default_language = "en"` it will be rendered as `Published on July 04, 2023`.

For `default_language = "de"` it will be rendered as `Veröffentlicht am 04. Juli 2023`.

## My question

I want to enable easy localization of my theme. The solutions mentioned above feels not elegant, and I'm not sure if there is a better solution, even one that the author of Zola - as of version v0.17.2 - envisioned for localization.

How would someone proficient in Zola and Tera tackle the problem?